# Please help me solve for $L-L^2$?

Tags: square-numbers

Unfortunately, I don't know any basic maths, and I need to solve the following equation for $L$ using the intercept of my graph:

$$\begin{aligned}
        intercept & = \frac{2L}{\pi^2 + L(L - 1)} \\
      \end{aligned}$$

So far, I have:

$$\begin{aligned}
        intercept & = \frac{2L}{\pi^2 + L^2 - L} \\
      \end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}
        intercept.\pi^2 + L^2 - L & = 2L \\
      \end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}
        intercept.\pi^2 & = 2L - L^2 + L \\
      \end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}
        intercept.\pi^2 & = 3L - L^2 \\
      \end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}
        \frac{intercept.\pi^2}{3} & = L - L^2 \\
      \end{aligned}$$

My excuse is that it's been a long time since I've done any basic maths, so I've probably rearranged it incorrectly... and I'm not sure what to do with the $L^2$, seeing as I need only one term for $L$ as I need to extract its value from the intercept of my graph. )

Comment: In the step where you divided by $3$ you forgot to divide $L^2$ by $3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me call the intercept $n$. The main mistake you made is that when you clear the denominator on the right side, the entire denominator multiplies with the left side. So you get

$$n(\pi^2+L^2-L)=2L.$$

This can be rearranged into a quadratic equation:

$$n\pi^2+nL^2-nL=2L \\
nL^2+(-n-2)L+n\pi^2=0.$$

So the solutions, if there are any, can be found with the quadratic formula.

Comment: Wonderful - thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that $intercept$ multiplies the whole denominator.
$$ intercept(\pi^2+L^2-L)=2L \\
   intercept \times \pi^2+intercept \times L^2 -intercept \times L =2L \\
   \pi^2=L-L^2+\frac{2L}{intercept}
$$

Now keep in mind that the whole left hand side is a constant, say $\pi^2=c$.

Then, $$c=L-L^2+\frac{2L}{intercept}\\ -L^2+(1+\frac{2}{intercept})L-c=0$$

Now use the quadratic formula with $a=-1,b=(1+\frac{2}{intercept}),c=-\pi^2$
$$L_1,L_2=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Now, you can get either 2, 1 or 0 roots, depending on the discriminant.

Comment: I think you have some mistakes, because $c$ contains $L$, so your expression is actually a fixed point equation. Presumably you mean to combine the $L$ term in $c$ into the $L$ term in the quadratic.

Comment: Thank you very much for both of your help :) It's good to see things from a different perspective!